# Solving nonlinear ODE: $(4x^3 - 3x^2y)dy - x^3dx = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(4x^3 - 3x^2y)dy - x^3dx = 0$

How can I solve the ODE above?

Is possible solve it as a non-exact ODE?

Comment: use the substitution $y = mx.$   find the separable de satisfied by $m.$

Comment: Note the equation is homogeneous.

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dy} + \frac{3y}{x} = 4$ this is the most far that I can go. As x is  $\frac{1}{x}$ i can't find P(x) or Q(x), this is the first time that it happens.. so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Abel can you explain better?

Comment: @abel gave a very nice hint, we have $y = m(x) x \implies y' = m' x + m$. Substitute those items in, simplify and you are left with a Separable Equation.

Comment: I'm substituting $w = x^3  \Rightarrow  w'= 3x^2dx$ in $(4x^3 - 3x^2y)\frac{dy}{dx} - x^3 = 0$ .. but it's not working.. and sorry I don`t uderstand what you mean with $y = m(x)x$ ... I'm really new with ODE sorry.

Comment: In the original equation, substitute $mx$ for $y$ wherever $y$ occurs. $m$ is a function as well, so $dy = mdx + xdm$. When you make that substitution you will find that the equation, now in terms of $m$ and $x$, is separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2\left((4x - 3y) - x\frac{dx}{dy}\right) = 0$$
A trivial solution is $x(y)=0$. Apart from that :
$$(4 - 3\frac{y}{x})\frac{dy}{dx} =1$$
This is an homogeneous ODE. So, let $\:u(x)=\frac{y}{x}$
$$(4 - 3u)(u+xu') =1$$
$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{3u+4}{3u^2+4u+1}u'=\frac{9}{2}\frac{u'}{3u+1}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{u'}{u+1}$$
$$\ln(x)=\frac{3}{2}\ln(3u+1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(u+1)+c$$
The solution, on parametric form, is :
\begin{cases}
    x=C (3u+1)^{3/2} (u+1)^{-1/2} \\
    y=x\,u  \\
  \end{cases}
In order to express the solution on the form $\:y(x)\:$ one have to eliminate the parameter $\:u\:$
$x^2=C^2 (3u+1)^3(u+1)^{-1}$
$$ (3u+1)^3-c\,x^2(u+1)=0$$
(with change of typography of the constant)

Solving for $\:u\:$ this cubic equation gives $\:u(x)\:$ and then $\:y(x)=x\,u(x)$